# AngularJS - Load javascript in ng-view

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, ng-view

I'm new with AngularJS and I would like to use some javascript library, in this case masonry library. It works fine except that I can't use it in partial html files where it does not work anymore. Where is problem or what should I do? I found that I have to add jQuery before AngularJS file but I have it and still nothing. Here is what I have:

index.html

```
<body ng-app="clientApp">


<!-- Add your site or application content here -->
<div class="header">

</div>

<div class="container">
    <div ng-view=""></div>
</div>



<script src="scripts/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script> <-- this does not work in ng-view

<!-- build:js(.) scripts/vendor.js -->
<!-- bower:js -->
<script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/assets/javascripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/lodash/dist/lodash.compat.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/restangular/dist/restangular.js"></script>
<!-- endbower -->
<!-- endbuild -->

<!-- build:js({.tmp,app}) scripts/scripts.js -->
<script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/controllers/main.js"></script>
<!-- endbuild -->
</body>
```

main.html

```
<h1>Masonry - columnWidth</h1>
<div class="masonry js-masonry"  data-masonry-options='{ "columnWidth": 60 }'>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item w2 h2"></div>
    <div class="item h3"></div>
    <div class="item h2"></div>
    <div class="item w3"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item h2"></div>
    <div class="item w2 h3"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item h2"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item w2 h2"></div>
    <div class="item w2"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item h2"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item h3"></div>
    <div class="item h2"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item h2"></div>
</div>
```

app.js

```
angular
    .module('clientApp', [
        'ngRoute',
        'restangular'
    ])
    .config(function ($routeProvider, RestangularProvider) {

        RestangularProvider.setBaseUrl('http://localhost:3000');

        $routeProvider
            .when('/', {
                templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
                controller: 'MainCtrl'
            })
            .otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/'
            });
    })
    .factory('MovieRestangular', function (Restangular) {
        return Restangular.withConfig(function (RestangularConfigurer) {
            RestangularConfigurer.setRestangularFields({
                id: '_id'
            });
        });
    })
    .factory('Movie', function(MovieRestangular) {
        return MovieRestangular.service('movie');
    });
```

and main.js

```
angular.module('clientApp')
  .controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.awesomeThings = [
      'HTML5 Boilerplate',
      'AngularJS',
      'Karma'
    ];
  });
```

Comment: Try this masonry directive instead, works well and stops muddying your code: https://github.com/passy/angular-masonry

Comment: I can try it but when I want to use another library then there is still this problem

Comment: (just had a peek at Masonry) you need to initialize your Masonry instance http://masonry.desandro.com/

Comment: I initialized it in HTML (also according manual), see main.html. Btw when I don't use partial file then masonry works fine